# Explain Betti diagram of a minimal free resolution for a simplical complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am self-learning algebraic geometry and reading the book `The Geometry of Syzygies A Second Course in Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra` and  I want to understand Problem 13 on the page 30 about first examples of free resolution:

1. what is the dot in $x_2x_3$? It is some sort of root because $x_3$ is not in any other monomial?
2. can you understand the Betti diagram a bit like connectivity digram where high-number means more connectivity among the monomials?

> [image]

Please explain

**How is the Betti diagram of a minimal free resolution generated here?**

*P.s. Thread on Betti diagrams in Tikz [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314162/how-to-create-betti-diagrams-in-tikz).*